# "idlogotipo" is not taking any values, what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've this schema.yml:

```
SdrivingEmpresa:
  columns:
    idempresa:
      type: integer(4)
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    idlogotipo:
      type: integer(4)
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
    nombre_empresa:
      type: string(250)
      notnull: true
    ruta_emp:
      type: string(45)
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SdrivingLogotipo:
      local: idlogotipo
      foreign: idlogotipo
      type: one
    SdrivingEmisor:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SdrivingMaquina:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SdrivingOperador:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SdrivingTurno:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SfGuardUserProfile:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
```

I wrote this code in `SdrivingLogotipoForm.class.php`

```
class SdrivingLogotipoForm extends BaseSdrivingLogotipoForm {

    public function configure() {
        $this->widgetSchema['archivo'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFile(array('label' => ''));
        $this->validatorSchema['archivo'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
            'required' => false,
            'path' => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'),
            'mime_types' => 'web_images',
        ));
    }

}
```

and this in `SdrivingEmpresaForm.class.php`:

```
class SdrivingEmpresaForm extends BaseSdrivingEmpresaForm {

    public function configure() {
        $logotipo = new SdrivingLogotipo();
        $logotipo->setIdlogotipo($logotipo);
        $this->embedForm('logotipo', new SdrivingLogotipoForm());
    }

}
```

When I execute the `create()` method the Empresa is saved and also the Logotipo file is uploaded but the field `idlogotipo` in SdrivingEmpresa gets `0`, why? What I'm doing wrong?

**Using widget from `SdrivingEmpresaForm`**

After read @1ed suggestion I made some changes, now `SdrivingEmpresaForm.class.php` have this code:

```
class SdrivingEmpresaForm extends BaseSdrivingEmpresaForm {

    public function configure() {
        $this->widgetSchema['idlogotipo'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFile(array('label' => ''));
        $this->validatorSchema['idlogotipo'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
            'required' => false,
            'path' => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'),
            'mime_types' => 'web_images',
        ));
    }

    public function doUpdateObject($values) {
        parent::doUpdateObject($values);

        if (isset($this['idlogotipo'])) {
            if ($this->isNew()) {
                $logotipo = new SdrivingLogotipo();
                $this->getObject()->setSdrivingLogotipo($logotipo);
            } else {
                $logotipo = $this->getObject()->getSdrivingLogotipo();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But when I send the form I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'idlogotipo' cannot be null

And logotipo file isn't uploaded and also isn't created. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `sfWidgetFormInputFile` not in an embedded for but in the `SdrivingEmpresaForm`

```
$this->setWidget('logotipo', new sfWidgetFormInputFile());
...
```

UPDATE:

If you want multiple files belong to a user, then you should move the id to the opposite side so the foreign key should be an empersa id in the logotipo table. To deal with these kind of relations is not convenient... there is a way described in the [docs](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms) or there is a [plugin](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/sfDoctrineDynamicFormRelationsPlugin) which may helps but it has limitations.

Comment: Ok, if I set the widget in `SdrivingEmpresaForm` then how I upload the file, insert the uploaded file in `SdrivingLogotipo` table and get the `id` of the inserted row for set then in `SdrivingEmpresa`? Is my logic fine or not? What is your suggestion among the one you leave here

Comment: Hmm, I think the relation doesn't make sense in this form :) Or the same file can belong to multiple users (empersa)? If you want multiple files belong to a user, than the foreign key should be an empersa id in the logotipo table. Or if it's a one-to-one relation is unnecessary and the file location should be stored in empersa.

Comment: no you're right one file for one users but I can't see which relation is wrong, which is?

Comment: Which one are we talking about? `SdrivingLogotipo` I think this relation is not needed at all, just use a `logotipo` string(255) type field instead.

Comment: so you mean I take out the `SdrivingLogotipo` relation from `SdrivingEmpresa` at `schema.yml` level and of course regenerate the models and forms or what?

Comment: Yes. I told you earlier that your schema smells and that will make your work more difficult. You should look over the whole schema especially for relations and correct the mistakes and speak to your team. Without a good schema your application will not work correctly for sure.

Comment: yes, I understood your point and yes you're right. I contact the others team members and they said in a near future each `empresa` can have more than one `logotipo` for that the relation so this takes me again to the first question, how to get the ID of the logotipo in order to insert in `SdrivingEmpresa` table?